# How to use basic functions on vector of objects with inheritance C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, inheritance, vector

I have `class Employee`, and class `Intern` which derived from `Employee`. I want to store Employee information in `vector<>` and use basic function on `vector` like `sort()`, `find_if` etc. As far as I know, I have to use pointers. The problem is I don't know how to use these functions on `vector< * >` Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Employee>> Firm;
hireIntern(Firm);
//////////////////////////////

void hireIntern(vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& sourceIntern) {

    string fillName;
    string fillSurname;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Intern Name: ";
    cin >> fillName;
    cout << "Enter Intern Surname: ";
    cin >> fillSurname;

    Intern newIntern(fillName, fillSurname);
    newIntern.setID();
    newIntern.Hire();
    newIntern.setSalary(1500);

    while (true) {  /*    1    */

        auto it = find_if(sourceIntern.begin(), sourceIntern.end(),
                          [&newIntern](const Employee &obj) { return obj.getID() == newIntern.getID(); });

        if (it != sourceIntern.end()) {
            newIntern.setID();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << newIntern.getName() << " " << newIntern.getSurname() << " (" << newIntern.getID()
         << ") has been hired" << endl;
    sourceIntern.emplace_back(new Intern());
    sortEmployeeIDs(sourceIntern);
}
              /*     2    */

void sortEmployeeIDs(vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {
        sort(sourceEmployee.begin(), sourceEmployee.end(), [&sourceEmployee](const Employee &left, const Employee &right) {
                return left.getID() < right.getID();
        });
}
```

EDIT: Updated code, now the problem is that Object doesn't seem to be saved in vector as I'm trying to `cout << i->getID();`

```
void hireIntern(vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& sourceIntern) {

    string fillName;
    string fillSurname;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Intern Name: ";
    cin >> fillName;
    cout << "Enter Intern Surname: ";
    cin >> fillSurname;

    Intern newIntern(fillName, fillSurname);
    newIntern.setID();
    newIntern.Hire();
    newIntern.setSalary(1500);

    while (true) {

        auto it = find_if(sourceIntern.begin(), sourceIntern.end(),
                          [&newIntern](const unique_ptr<Employee> &obj) { return obj->getID() == newIntern.getID(); });

        if (it != sourceIntern.end()) {
            newIntern.setID();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << newIntern.getName() << " " << newIntern.getSurname() << " (" << newIntern.getID()
         << ") has been hired" << endl;
    sourceIntern.emplace_back(new Intern());
    sortEmployeeIDs(sourceIntern);
    for(const auto &i : sourceIntern) {
        cout << i->getID();
    }
}
```

Comment: At point 2 you try to sort pointers, but supply a comparison for non-pointers. Similar problem at point 1, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `std::find_if` and `std::sort` will pass the elements of the vector to your comparison functors, as if by `test_func(*iter)` or `compare_func(*iter1, *iter2)`.  You have written your lambdas to take `const Employee&` arguments, but the vector elements are actually `std::unique_ptr<Employee>` objects.

If you write the lambdas to take the correct type, it should work.  (Also, notice you don't need to capture `sourceEmployee` in the comparison lambda, since you don't use it.)

```
[&newIntern](std::unique_ptr<Employee>& ptr)
{ return ptr->getID() == newIntern.getID(); }

[](std::unique_ptr<Employee>& left, std::unique_ptr<Employee>& right)
{ return left->getID() < right->ID(); }
```

I know you tagged the question [c++11], but if you can use C++14 or later, you could write `auto&` instead of `std::unique_ptr<Employee>&` as a lambda parameter.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. Now functions work fine and I learned how to implement them. When it comes to `while` loop you mentioned, let me explain what I'm doing here. While loop was made to avoid setting duplicate ID for employee. I'm doing `find_if` to look for duplicated ID. If it's fine i quit the loop, if there's a duplicate I do `setID()` (mt19937 random num from 10k-9,9k) and loop again to find if it's another duplication. So at this point I don't understand the solution you gave me.

Comment: @Taknie Oh, I see. So you actually do want to scan the entire vector each time. Never mind the last part then.

Comment: One again, thanks for helping me. Your answer was the solution. Now I'm going to implement rest of functions in my database that way. If an error occurs I will reply once again and ask, If you don't mind :)

Comment: @Taknie If you get stuck on another issue in compiling or running the program, please open a new question describing that issue.

Comment: I updated the post. Could you have a look please? I guess I have to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, but saving info to vector doesn't work.